# BigDecimal equals <= and >= best practice

Tags: java, bigdecimal

I can compare 2 BigDecimal objects with `compareTo()` method

```
BigDecimal val = new BigDecimal(10);

val.compareTo(new BigDecimal(11)) //return -1 

val < 11 - -1
val = 11 - 0
val > 11 - 1
```

But How can I compare val >= and <= ???

```
if(val.compareTo(new BigDecimal(11) ==-1) || val.compareTo(new BigDecimal(11) ==0)) // val <= 11
```

But it is Crooked somehow

Comment: `val1.compareTo(val2) <= 0`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
if(val.compareTo(new BigDecimal(11)) <= 0) //val <=11
if(val.compareTo(new BigDecimal(11)) >= 0) //val >=11
```

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you messed up the curvy brackets. It shouldn't compile this way. The comparison is within the method call. Within your if:

> val.compareTo(**new BigDecimal(11) ==-1**)

The bold part is evaluated first. But the == operator won't work for BigDecimal and int.

You propably meant:

```
    if ( 
        val.compareTo(new BigDecimal(11)) == -1 
     || val.compareTo(new BigDecimal(11)) ==  0 
                                                )
```